# Ruby strftime: don't show minutes if zero

Tags: ruby, strftime

I'm trying to achieve this style of output:

```
Time.new(2021,9,19,6,0,0) => "6am"
Time.new(2021,9,19,6,30,0) => "6:30am"
```

Closest I've gotten is `strftime('%l:%-M%P')` which yields:

```
Time.new(2021,9,19,6,0,0).strftime('%-l:%-M%P') => "6:0am"
Time.new(2021,9,19,6,30,0).strftime('%-l:%-M%P') => "6:30am"
```

Is there a known way to suppress `%M` or `%-M` when zero, or am I going to need to do my own thing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have to do your own thing but this is a simple way to do it.

```
time.strftime('%-l:%M%P').sub(':00', '')
```

Comment: ... or `t = Time.new(2021,9,19,6,0,0); t.strftime("%-l#{t.min.zero? ? '' : ':%-M'}%P") #=> "6am"`. Similarly, `t2 = Time.new(2021,9,19,6,30,0); t2.strftime("%-l#{t.min.zero? ? '' : ':%-M'}%P") #=> "6:30am"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, nice use of interpolation! Though I do think Steve's answer is easier to read.

Comment: Dear Diary.  Today, someone thought my answer was better than @CarySwoveland 's. :D